# Railscasts 258 Token Fields - Set additional attributes in :through table - the rails way to do it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, associations, has-many-through, jquery-tokeninput

I'm having a problem based on the excellent RailsCast #258 from Ryan Bates.

The situation is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :capabilities,
           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :skills, :through => :capabilities,
           :uniq => true

  has_many :raters,
           :through => :capabilities,
           :foreign_key => :rater_id,
           :uniq => true

  attr_accessible :name, :skill_tokens
  attr_reader :skill_tokens      

  def skill_tokens=(tokens)
      self.skill_ids = Skill.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  end
end

class Capability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rater, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :skill

  validates_uniqueness_of :rater_id, :scope => [:user_id, :skill_id]
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :capabilities
  has_many :users, :through => :capabilities,
           :uniq => true

  has_many :raters, :through => :capabilities,
           :foreign_key => :rater_id
end
```

The form contains a normal textfield for the skill tokens which are passed as ids:

```
.field  
    = f.label :skill_tokens, "Skills"
    = f.text_field :skill_tokens, data: {load: @user.skills}
```

So a user can get many skills assigned through capabilities. While assigning the skill, the rater should also be tracked in the capability model.

Using Ryans example of jquery TokenInput I created an appropriate form to allow a user to assign (and create) skills using a tokenInput text field.

The Problem lies now in processing the data and setting the rater before the association is saved.

Through some ruby magic, self.skill_ids on the user model sets the ids used for the association model creation so the controller action is quite simple:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])      
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Obviously, if I want to set the additional rater attribute on the capability model it won't work so easily with update_attributes.

So how can I achieve this with "the rails way" to do it - writing beautiful, readable code?
ANY help would be greately appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the `rater_id`?

**If you plan accept a user input for the rater for each skill the user adds on the form,** 
I can't see how you'll be able to use input fields based on token inputs to achieve this. You're going to have to choose some other types of inputs.

**If you plan to set the rater to the currently logged in user, or are setting the rater based on some other business logic**, my approach would be overwriting the `skill_ids=` method in the User model to work how you want it, adding an attr_accessor to store the current_rater and passing the current_rate from the controller.

Something like:

```
#user.rb
attr_accessor :current_rater
def skill_ids=(ids)
  return false if current_rater.nil? || User.find_by_id(current_rater).nil?
  capabilities.where("skill_id not in (?)", ids).destroy_all
  ids.each do |skill_id|      
    capabilities.create(:skill_id => skill_id, :rater_id => self.current_rater) if capabilities.find_by_id(skill_id).nil?
  end
end

#users_controller.rb
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  #Replace 'current_user' with whatever method you are using to track the logged in user
  params[:user].merge(:current_rater => current_user) 

  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

Probably not as elegant as you were hoping, but it should do the job?